# Is my data safe with encryption?

Tags: php, mysql

In storing passwords in php mysql, can i assume the passwords to be safe if i were to run md5 algorithm again and again and with combination of text replacement and rotation?

Comment: Full answer: Nope.

Comment: Define "safe". Safe from your meddlesome 8 year old sister? Safe from professional rivals? Safe from major organized crime and terror groups?

Comment: [Warning
It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm. See the Password Hashing FAQ for details and best practices.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php)

Comment: md5 is NOT encryption!

Comment: Curious why you are asking. Is this just because you are interested in the problem in general? Are you aware of `password_hash` and `password_verify`?

Answer (score 2):

No, MD5 is not secure to use to create a password verifier.

With PHP use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), the pair are secure and easy to use.

When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions with about a 100ms duration. Make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.